# Apache server running on PHP ver. 8.0.1 won't load React/ZMQ extension on startup

Tags: php, cakephp, zeromq

I am trying to experiment web sockets with cakephp ver 4. My server is WAMP 3.2.6 x64 running on Win 10 and PHP 8.1.0 set as preferred engine version. It turns out that zmq-extension has to be enabled in php.ini file.
And there lies my problem: I've searched many stackoverflow solutions, that seem to have been usuful for older php and OS versions, but none seems to work for my configuration.
Is it possible that php_zmq is not fixed for running on php 8? Or, maybe WAMP 3.2.6 is to blame?
Thanks in advance for your prompt replies!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution for me was to downgrade php to version 7.2.34. All other attempted php versions, up to ver 8.0.1 at least, were futile.